# can i do insert,update and delete operation on cassandra 3 database using apache MetaModel?

Tags: cassandra, apache-metamodel

I can do select operation from cassandra database using Apache MetaModel.But insert,delete,and update operation is not happening.
I am using latest cassendra version 3.0.7 and using datastax/java driver.
After that i have used cassandra-jdba driver.So, when i am trying to create updatablejdbcContext using cassandra connection, it is giving error:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to Cassandra via MetaModel you don't need supply a driver. MetaModel takes care of the driver dependency and hides it from you as a user.

When creating CassandraDataContext, you need to specify the keyspace. I suspect the keyspace you specified does not match the keyspace from the Cassandra instance you are running. You might need to first create a new keyspace after a fresh installation of Cassandra.

You should provide a code snippet how you are trying to use MetaModel. Otherwise it is hard to find where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. I am following what u have suggested...but it is not working...i will provide a code snippet with the problem ....